# Under Unifiedjs ecosystem, what does RECMA stand for?

Tags: javascript, markdown, remarkjs, rehypejs

So when parsing mdx, you typically use remark plugins for markdown, and rehype plugins for HTML. I see a third category called recma plugins. What does recma stand for and what is it? Google surprisingly has no results on this.

For example, this plugin: https://github.com/remcohaszing/recma-nextjs-static-props

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless someone knows better, I assert that 'recma' is a *cutsie* overloading of the letter 'e' yielding [Remark (re)](https://remark.js.org/) and [ECMAScript (ecma)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript). I have an interest in this topic so I dug as deep as my free time would allow.

Here are the more citable references I was able to find:

1. [docs.astro.build: recmaPlugins](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/mdx/#recmaplugins):

   - `recmaPlugins`: These are plugins that modify the output [estree](https://github.com/estree/estree#the-estree-spec) directly. This is useful for modifying or injecting [JavaScript](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) variables in your [MDX](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary/mdx/) files.
2. [GitHub: #2030 Provide recma packages similar to remark](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/issues/2030):

   - What plugin are you making?

     - A plugin which makes all global variables available in pages/_app.js in [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/learn/foundations/about-nextjs/what-is-nextjs) projects by injecting `getStaticProps`.
3. [mdxjs: options.recmaPlugins](https://mdxjs.com/packages/mdx/#optionsrecmaplugins):

   - recma plugins are a new [ecosystem](https://github.com/unifiedjs/collective#teams) currently in beta to transform esast [*was this supposed to be [estree](https://github.com/estree/estree#the-estree-spec)?*] trees ([JavaScript](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)).
4. [npmjs: xdm, Compilers, Babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xdm/v/1.5.1#:%7E:text=A%20%E2%80%9Crecma%E2%80%9D%20plugin%20is%20a%20unified%20plugin%20that%20runs%20on%20the%20estree):

   - recma plugins are a new ecosystem currently in beta to transform esast [*was this supposed to be [estree](https://github.com/estree/estree#the-estree-spec)?*] trees ([JavaScript](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)).
5. [Github: recma-nextjs-static-props](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/36816#:%7E:text=recma%2Dnextjs%2Dstatic%2Dprops%20is%20a%20minimal%20Next.js%20project.%20and%20can%20be%20used%20as%20a%20project):

   - Is a minimal [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/learn/foundations/about-nextjs/what-is-nextjs) project...
   - Exposes Next.js applications' top-level scope Identifiers...
   - Generates `getStaticProps` - exposing top-level identifiers.
6. [recma-nextjs-static-props](https://github.com/remcohaszing/recma-nextjs-static-props)

   - This plugin is intended for use with Next.js and [MDX](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary/mdx/). It injects a `getStaticProps` function which exposes all top level identifiers. This means these variable are available in pages/_app.js.

**CAVEAT!** I am new to the [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) world and the [Unified collective](https://github.com/unifiedjs/collective#teams). Much of what I find seems to assume you are well steeped in the paradigm. This is unfortunate and it makes learning difficult - IMO.